# Clean logging with BASH

Tags: bash, logging

I have a script that deletes files 7 days or older and then logs them to a folder. It logs and deletes everything correctly but when I open up the log file for viewing, its very sloppy.

```
log=$HOME/Deleted/$(date) 
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime +7 -delete -print > "$log"
```

The log file is difficult to read

Example File Output: (when opened in notepad)

```
/home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file1.txt/home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file2.txt/home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file3.txt
```

Is there anyway to log the file nicer and cleaner? Maybe with the Filename, date deleted, and how old it was?

Any suggestions help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure try multiple exec statements like:

```
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime +7 -exec ls -latr "{}" \; -exec echo was deleted on `date` \; -exec rm -f "{}" \;|paste - - >> "$log"
```

Comment: +1 for `paste` trick

Comment: log=$HOME/Deleted/$(date)
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -latr {} \; -      exec echo was deleted on `date` \; -exec rm -f "{}" \;|paste - - >> $log


that looks right but i keep getting this error and i dont know why

./test.sh: line 3: $log: ambiguous redirect
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13

Comment: @MattKrouse: The variable `log` contains white spaces (as it is derived from `date`: `Fr Jun 28 16:49:19 CEST 2013`), so the redirection `>> $log` should read `>> "$log"` like in your question. And probably you want to enclose also the ls parameter `{}` in quotes, like in the `rm` statement: `... -exec ls -latr "{}" ...`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can you answer another question? My log file now looks like this..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u0146121 Domain Users 0 Jun 27 15:28 /home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file1.txt Was deleted on Fri, Jun 28, 2013 10:08:28 AM

What is the "-rwxr-xr-x 1 u0146121 Domain Users" part? Can I modify that at all?

Comment: @mpy alright, gotta do what you gotta do

Comment: @MattKrouse: You should make you comfortable with some basic linux commands... use e.g. `ls -l` and you will see the `-rwxr-xr-x...` part (this are the permission/owner/group), too. Use `man ls` for a more detailed explanation of the `ls` command. If you don't like that, simply omit the `-l` parameter in the find command: `...-exec ls -atr "{}"`. However then you will lose the modification date, too. I don't know an easy solution right now if you want to keep the date (that would make another good question).

Comment: If you want the modification date from ls -l you can pipe it through awk {print $6"-"$7"-"$8}'  Or use stat -c %y <filename>

Comment: The `-a` option of `ls` is meaningless when applied to file argument(s).  (`ls –l .bashrc` works fine; you don’t need to say `ls –la`.)  And the `-t` and `-r` options are meaningful only when you have multiple arguments, or one (or more) directory argument(s).  So, since you’re saying `-type f`, you might as well say just `-exec ls -l {}`.

Comment: Good point Scott.  Not sure why I used all those switches.

Comment: @Gregg: Belatedly, welcome to Super User.  For your information, when you respond to a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”.  That way he gets notified.  You can abbreviate, or use an entire name (without spaces) as in “@GreggLeventhal”.  The author of a post is automatically notified of comments to that post (as, I presume, you have experienced).  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.