# find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13 error

Tags: bash, logging

**My Script**

```
log=$HOME/Deleted/$(date)
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -latr {} \; -exec echo was deleted on `date` \; -exec rm -f "{}" \;|paste - - >> $log
```

My goal for the script is to delete files older than x amount of days and then log them to a file and display the filename, date deleted, and how old it was.
I keep getting these errors however...

```
./test.sh: line 3: $log: ambiguous redirect
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve here? It will help anybody trying to answer your question as well as anybody searching for similar questions.

Comment: Sure I updated it for you.

Comment: Downvote, because this is a follow-up to http://superuser.com/q/612930/195224

Comment: @mpy so? What if it is a follow up? Nothing wrong with that, the OP very correctly posted a new question rather than cluttering the comments of their previous question. That is exactly what they should do. There is no reason to downvote, it is a perfectly clear question.

Comment: @terdon 
 Thanks for sticking up for the little guy! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Just so you know, @mpy is only trying to be a good SU user, I am sure he has nothing against you personally and I have nothing but respect for the quality of [his answers](http://superuser.com/a/602824/151431). We just disagree on this particular point.

Comment: @terdon: Follow up was probably the wrong word. The [answer](http://superuser.com/a/612937/195224) to the other question had [issues](http://superuser.com/questions/612930/clean-logging-with-bash#comment759593_612937). So I thought it would be better to correct the answer in the first place instead of raising a new question on the error of those answer. (And that is what I tried to do with my comment and after acknowledgement by OP with my [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/612937/revisions). So, mkrouse, it really has nothing to do with "little guy" -- I helped you, where it IMHO belongs to.

Comment: The `-a` option of `ls` is meaningless when applied to file argument(s).  (`ls –l .bashrc` works fine; you don’t need to say `ls –la`.)  And the `-t` and `-r` options are meaningful only when you have multiple arguments, or one (or more) directory argument.  So, since you’re saying `-type f`, you might as well say just `-exec ls -l {}`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, based on your previous question, you want `-mtime +7` for 7 days or older. `-mtime -7` means 7 days old or newer.

The `ambiguous redirect` error probably means that `$log` is not defined. I cannot reproduce your `find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13` it probably depends on the specific files you have in the folder in question. Could you post the file list somewhere?

Anyway, `signal 13` [means a broken pipe](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/linux_pgsignals.html) so something is going wrong. Are you piping this command through `head` or `tail` or similar? Try this and see if you get the same errors:

```
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/  -type f -mtime +7 -exec stat -c "%n %y"  "{}" \; -exec echo was deleted on `date` \; |paste - - >>$log
```

Comment: `ambiguous redirection` can also be caused by white spaces in `$log`; try this in bash: `log=$(date); echo foo > $log`, this failes, while `log=$(date); echo foo > "$log"` is working fine.

Comment: Well, putting the pieces together here: if there’s something about `$log` (such as unescaped, unquoted embedded spaces) that makes `>> $log` fail, then that means that the `paste` process never gets started, and so the `find` is piping into nothing.  But `find` isn’t writing to its standard output; it’s only spawning child processes (`ls` and `echo`) that do.  (`rm` also shares the same stdout; i.e., the broken pipe, but it doesn’t write anything to it.)  So, each time `find` fork/execs `ls` and `ls` writes, it gets a broken pipe signal.

Comment: The only question is: Why doesn’t `echo` exhibit the same behavior?  I guess it probably has something to do with the fact that `echo` is a shell builtin command.